# Can you lookup friends of friends with the Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app needs to generate a list of friends for the logged in user, as well as the friends of the friends. The logged in user has authorized the app. So I have no trouble getting their friends. When I make the `/friends/` call to the API using one of the friends' IDs, I get this error message:

```
Can't lookup all friends of [FB ID]. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.
```

I knew that the public visibility of one's friends is a configurable setting for each individual user, but if I understand this message correctly it means that you simply cannot do what I'm trying... ever.

Question #1: Is this true? Is there simply no way to lookup someone's friends' friends?
Question #2: If it's not possible, how do sites like Glassdoor.com manage this exact functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the friends of friends of the person who is using the app.

Glassdoor.com sends invitations to the user's friends and when someone accepts, they simply get his friends since he becomes a user of their app.